# Simple 2 Block Mobile Navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm trying to make a simple navigation that will be served on mobile devices where it is a grid like layout. There are two blocks on one row and there will be 3 rows. There is 5 links so the total number will be odd. Since the number is odd I am trying to make the current page class take up the whole width instead of having two links in a row.

Something like this very crude drawing:
[image]

Or if link 3 is the current page:

[image]

Currently I have a basic 5 link list. Here is the HTML:

```
            <nav id="primary_nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a '. $this->getCurrentPage("contact") .' href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a '. $this->getCurrentPage("portfolio") .' href="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a '. $this->getCurrentPage("resume") .' href="Resume">Resume</a></li>
                    <li><a '. $this->getCurrentPage("bio") .' href="Bio">Bio</a></li>
                    <li><a '. $this->getCurrentPage("index") .' href="Home">Home</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#primary_nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: #1c1c1c;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

#primary_nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    line-height: 2em;
    height: 3em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #383838;
}

#primary_nav li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}

#primary_nav li a:hover,
#primary_nav li a:focus {
    color: #1c1c1c;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: How would you want it to look if, for example, link 2 were selected. Should It occupy the middle row and have link 3 move up?

Comment: Which ever is easier really. I didn't think of that case. The current class is more a bell and whistle than core which is the structure. If you can show me how to construct that it would be fine.

Comment: When moving link 2 to the middle, you'd have to move link3 to link2s base position. That's a change to big to do with css alone (actually with some new stuff from css3 you could do it easily, however browser support is still lacking). Is using javascript/jquery an option?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with both and am willing to learn them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget javascript, you can do it with css alone (no fancy css3).

Here's the Html...

```
<nav id="primary_nav">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="selected"><a href="Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="Resume">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="Bio">Bio</a></li>
      <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>​
```

...and here's the CSS...

```
#primary_nav {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#primary_nav li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#primary_nav li:nth-child(-n+3){
    margin-bottom: 40px; /*must match height set on "primary_nav a"*/
}

#primary_nav .selected {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px; /*must match height set on "primary_nav a"*/
    width: 100%;
}

#primary_nav a {
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px 10px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    height: 40px; 
}
```

​
All you need is to add `class="selected"` to the link referencing the currently selected page.

See it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/eYJG7/

Comment: This is perfect, Thanks for the putting it up in jsfiddle too!